# Best technique for storing custom map polygons in Android and ray casting

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, raycasting

I'm fairly new to Android and trying to develop an app that identifies if a user's location is inside or outside of a given region within a state. My approach is to take the user's latlng and use ray casting to identify which region they are inside (they must be inside 1). My regions are best equated to state park lines, but Google does not have these in Google Maps (and they're too irregular for geofencing). As such, I created customer polygons. I'm not struggling with the code, but struggling with the best way to handle data.

How should I store and access the polygon data for ray casting? I was taking the approach of storing the polygons in an XML file but I'm worried about the time and processing power it may take to parse the XML and run a ray casting across up to 30 polygons in a given state. My polygons are complex enough that the XML file for one state is upwards of 4MB. My polygons only need to be read, not written, as they'll come with the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your best option is to store your polygons is a geographic database. The best solution I've found so far to do so is [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial) which is build over SQLite and works really well on Android.

Using this approach you will store you polygons in the database and query what polygons intersect with a given LatLng (Point). The query will look like this (not tested):

```
select * from polygons_table where st_intersects(Geometry, MakePoint(longitude, latitude, 4326));
```

Note that I use 4326 as the SRID because I assume that you will store your polygons in WGS84.

[Here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/spatialite-sql-3.0.0.html) you can find the *SpatiaLite 3.0.0-BETA SQL functions reference list*.